# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()

Tags: eclipse, log4j

I am getting this error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()
at the runtime in eclipse. However, eclipse shows the method on doing intelligence search, but at runtime it fails to identify it.
I am using the latest log4j1.2.16 jar and it is added in the classpath.

Any suggestions?

Comment: any other jars used along with log4j 1.1.16 ?

Comment: Are you using log4j in a project that has that library (that jar file) in its Java Build Path? Check your project properties: `Java Build Path > Tab Libraries`.

Comment: There are other jars but not related to log4j. @mliebelt - yes, I included it in the java build path...but still doesn't identify it at runtime

Comment: @Shaggy, did you manage to overcome it?